# Multimedia keyboard

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

I am trying to use a multimedia keyboard with my Dell OptiPlex 320 using XP Home SP3. I tried a Logitech 600 and could not get any of the multimedia keys to work. I have ordered a Dell 8135 keyboard but have not yet received it. My question is this:
My computer has integrated sound which I disabled and added a M-Audio Revolution 5.1.
The M-Audio has worked great for several years with no major problems. Could this add-in sound card be my problem? Should I only use the integrated sound with a multimedia KB?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the [Logitech 600 keyboard software](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/434/2996&cl=us,en?WT.ac=sc|downloads||dd)?

Answer (score 0):

Did the keyboard come with any kind of cd? Usually multimedia keyboards require drivers or have an external software package that is required for the multimedia keys to work properly.

Another thing you can do is go to your keyboard settings and see if you can map those keys to anything. That can be found in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the CD that came with the keyboard and I installed an update from the Logitech site.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. My HID service was corrupt and not starting. Once I fixed it, all is well.

Thanks.